# Immediate captcha feedback via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, captcha

I wonder how bad it would be to give the users an immediate feedback whether a captcha they entered is correct or not. I think this would be a much better user experience. But I really can't remember to have this seen on any other page.

Now, how bad could it be? Well, come to think of it, a bot could figure the captcha out by brute force, but with 10^12 possible captchas it would not be very efficient to do this, just so that they could post one single comment or whatsoever, right?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: First of all: doing it by ajax or not is not a big deal. The problem is that whenever you submit a form new captcha is generated when you are wrong. And that would be a security issue. Because if you don't generate new captcha on AJAX, then it is a lot easie to create a dictionary of your captchas (a bot can focus on one captcha only).

Comment: but i store the captcha for each session and whenever i generate a new one, the old one will be no longer valid, so no security issue?